# Hiding Fields in Forms in List Instances Based on List Definitions

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, list-definition, xml

I have a list definition that I've created in XML, and multiple list instances based on that definition. On the base list definition I am hiding certain fields from the new item form in the list definition schema.xml, as such:

```
<Field
   ID="{3E39F835-6DE9-41B8-A305-906F86DB609C}"
   Name="ExecutiveDashboardDueDateDraftBook"
   StaticName="ExecutiveDashboardDueDateDraftBook"
   DisplayName="Due Date: Draft Book"
   Type="DateTime"
   Format="DateOnly"
   Group="Executive Dashboard Columns"
   ShowInNewForm="FALSE"
   ShowInEditForm="TRUE"
   ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE" />
```

Other fields I have showing in the new item form:

```
<Field
    ID="{1EB0EAE1-DD67-44F9-AF78-5B5EDD18788C}"
    Name="ExecutiveDashboardDueDateFinalBook"
    StaticName="ExecutiveDashboardDueDateFinalBook"
    DisplayName="Due Date: Final Book"
    Type="DateTime"
    Format="DateOnly"
    Group="Executive Dashboard Columns"
    ShowInNewForm="TRUE"
    ShowInEditForm="TRUE"
    ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE" />
```

Is there a way in XML, on a list instance created from this definition, that I can specify what fields are visible in a new item form? Or even control the visibility at all for the field overall, i.e. show / hide the field altogether? Or is my only option to dive into some C# in a feature activated event receiver to change this once the list instance has been provisioned to the site?

Here is an example list instance I have:

```
<ListInstance Title="Submissions"
            OnQuickLaunch="FALSE"
            TemplateType="106"
            FeatureId="0c6906da-a35f-46f5-80b5-6857b138be6d"
            Url="Lists/SubmissionsEvents"
            Description="Use this list for entering submission events.">
</ListInstance>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bit confused are you using a custom list definition or Microsoft one, the reason I ask is that the list instance is referencing a template of 106, the Event List, which is an out of the box list def.

You will need to use a copy of the schema.xml that Microsoft or you have created for the Event list. Find the definition in the SharePointRoot/Template/Features directory Associate the schema.xml with the list instance by using the ListInstance's CustomSchema attribute.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms476062.aspx

Now you have a copy of the schema, you can modify that List Instance's field configuration by modifying the field elements as required.